# Animations not working with mid air targets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm very new to Unity and Vuforia, and I wanted to make make an android app where you press a UI button on screen and an animation will play with the AR model. I looked at tutorials but I can't find ones that use mid air targets instead of image targets. Do animations just not work on mid air targets? Or am I missing something obvious?

I've tried using `animation.Play()`, using Optimize Transform Hierarchy, using Build Generic Avatar, checking and unchecking static batching. I tested it with image targets, and it worked, but I'm trying to see if I can do it with mid air targets.

Right now my code looks like this:

```cs
public class plsWork : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;

    public void PlayAnim()
    {
        anim.Play("doorAnimation");
        Debug.Log("play anim");
    }

    public void StopAnim()
    {
        anim.Play("idle");
        Debug.Log("idle");
    }
}
```